# How do I use the bombers?

Tags: battlefield-1942

I have been playing this game regularly for a week and I still can't figure out how to use the bombers. I see all the levels have them and I can tell where they are (marked by 3 little airplanes on mini map) but how the heck do you use these things? Everytime I try to enter the little radar station nothing happens. Last night I sat at the door the whole game waiting for something to pop up or the door to open and nothing ever happened.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to activate something else to get into the control room? It's possible I'm an idiot and am missing a red herring because I see them flying around all the time so I know most people know how to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radar station is what you need to enter to trigger the air raid. There should be a notice on your screen that the air raid is ready to be used or you can visually see the radar dish spinning on top of the bunker. After that you simply enter the bunker to trigger the air raid. As to why you aren't able to use them I can only think of two things. Either the bunker is already in use (radar dish is spinning and the light is on) or the air raid has recently been used, so the cool down is in effect.

Comment: So keep an eye out for an on screen notification and if the radar dish is spinning it's ready, but if the dish is spinning and a light is on someone else is using it... I will give it a shot tonight, thanks!

Comment: It's been about a year since I last played the game but I'm almost positive the first time the air raid becomes available for use you see an on screen notification. I might be wrong though.